# How do i get the TFS workitem(Task or Bug) Icon in Rest api?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I need to get the icon url for differntiating workItem types(task,bug,user stroy or Product Backlog) in Rest call

Comment: Can I also change that workItem of task from yellow color to some color

Comment: I'd advise you to read [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be more precise, provide code or error messages,..

Answer (score 1):

**To get workitem Icon**  in Rest API, it's impossible for now.

**To change the color**, you could try below steps:

1. Open the Command Prompt
2. CD cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
3. witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection:your col. /p:project /f:file
4. Edit the exported file, see below
5. witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:your col. /p:project /f:file

The process config should contain a section work item colors, if the section is missing just add it (e.g. at the end just before the end of ProjectProcessConfiguration)

```
<WorkItemColors>
 <WorkItemColor primary="FF009CCC" secondary="FFD6ECF2" name="Product Backlog Item" />
 <WorkItemColor primary="FFF2CB1D" secondary="FFF6F5D2" name="Task" />
 <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC293D" secondary="FFFAEAE5" name="Bug" />
</WorkItemColors>
```

The primary color is used in lists and the secondary color in boards.

Comment: ok..Thanks @Patrick-MSFT